# SCALA Lift - MongoDB JsonObjectField Convert List to JSON

Tags: json, scala, mongodb, lift

I've got a json object field in mongodb and was wondering if there was an elegant way of mapping the following list:

```
List(("Label_1","Value_1"),("Label_2","Value_2"))
```

Into a json object like:

```
var json = {

    Label_1 : "Value_1",
    Label_2 : "Value_2"

}
```

And then saving the object into a json object field called "thelist":

```
TheRecord.createRecord.title("Test Title").thelist(json).save
```

Thanks for any help in advance, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Json.toJson(
  List(("Label_1","Value_1"),("Label_2","Value_2")).map { item =>
    item._1 -> item._2
  }.toMap
)
```